# Hosting nodejs as windows service

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, iis

[image]I have hosted my nodejs application on windows as a windows service using http://nssm.cc/ .

However, when the application crashes it does not restart automatically.

I believe windows is not notified about the crash.

Also I cannot view the logs i have written in the console of the app for debugging.

Can anyone please assist with the best way to host nodejs on windows as a  service and check failure logs?
Also is IISNode a better approach?

Comment: I would try using Forever, there is a Windows fork: https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever-win

Comment: Make use of PM2 tool. also there is pm2-windows-service module to run as service.

Comment: Thanks.
But what about logs? How will I get notified about errors/crash? 

Any idea with IIS Node?

Comment: Both Forever and PM2 allow you to specify logging configuration. For alerts that's a separate issue. You could use Amazon CloudWatch Logs or a third-party service like Loggly or LogEntries.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) module that has windows [startup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-windows-startup) and [service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-windows-service) support, [log](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/) and [monitoring](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/monitoring/) management.

Comment: i should still host node as windows service? or PM2 takes care of it?

Comment: PM2 runs as a service and he (re)runs your code and takes care of everytrhing

Comment: I am getting error shown in above screenshot, can you please assist further?

Comment: please describe your system, OS, Node.js version, etc.. have you seen the instructions? you must have Node.js 4+ https://github.com/jon-hall/pm2-windows-service

Comment: I am using windows 8 and node version v5.7.1. I did check the instructions.

Comment: i see in the error message it says "error git not found" do you have git installed? https://git-scm.com/

Comment: Yes, I do have git. I have noticed that the service is installed but it stops within a second after i start it.

Below is error logged in event viewer -

Child process [7552 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --harmony "C:\Users\Intel_pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2-windows-service\node_modules\node-windows\lib\wrapper.js" -f "C:\Users\Intel_pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2-windows-service\src\service.js" -l "PM2" -g 0.25 -w 1 -r 3 -a n] terminated with 0